# Conditional SQL where clause in Java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

We are looking to to conditionally add where clauses to a SQL where class

For example we have a DAO that has a method with say 10 params.

For each of those params we check if it is null, if not we add an AND to the where clause.

The "base" query is a hard coded string and we concat it with the ANDS.

I'm looking for ideas for a more elegent way of doing this.

We are using hibernate elsewhere in the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Hibernate criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html) to dynamically build queries.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you can use variable argument method  and start a loop for  array and check for not null and concat it. otherwise you can use the Hibernate criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate Criteria might be what you want.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/

http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html